# Adding relationships without lookups in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA/Hibernate. I notice that when I am persisting a new object that I have to do a lookup for referent fields. For example, if I have a one-to-one relationship with Person and Address. And I want each address to refer to only one Person. AND I *know* the pimary key of the Person that I still have to do a lookup on Person to persist an Address.

```
@Transactional
public void saveAddressFor( Long personId, <adddress_details> ) {
   Address address = new Address();
   address.setOwner( em.getReference( Person.class, personId ) );
   address.setAddress( <address_details> );
   em.persist( address );
}
```

I was hoping that because I know the Person PKEY that by using #getReference that I would not have to look it up merely to get its PKEY for setting on insert. But when I inspect the SQL trace I see that at the end of the transaction it actually does lookup the Person before performing the INSERT.

Is there a way to avoid this lookup? It's not a huge deal, it's just unnecessary and I'd like to get rid of these if possible.

Comment: What JPA implementation are you using? Hibernate? What version?

Comment: 4.2.4 is JPA 2.0.  But anyways, what is your cascade on the owner field of the address class? Try making it none.  Otherwise, per javadocs the JPA impl is free to query the reference in a database operation (the lazily fetch properties part of the spec notes this).

Comment: Cascade is already none.

Comment: I mean it is probably having to load it to see if it should throw an EntityNotFoundException on #getReference. So I'm just wondering if there is a way to persist Address without having to load Person. I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to do with the following hibernate properties:

```
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="150"/>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value ="true"/>
```

To order inserts, for some reason, Hibernate will iterate through all the entity fields of the object it is persisting (even if CascadeType is NONE) and call #hashCode on each field. Calling #hashCode will cause the reference proxy to be loaded from the database.

For 4.2.4.Final you can see the code in ActionQueue.java line 799 where #findBatchNumber is called. The offending line number for #findBatchNumber is 856 where this code is called:

```
       Integer associationBatchNumber = entityBatchNumber.get( value );
```

In this case "value" will be the Person reference. This causes #hashCode to be called on it which will require it to be loaded from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is correct.  Normally `getReference()` will simply give you a reference object WITHOUT going to DB.

If you actually see it loading from DB, it is quite possibility that in your code, you have accessed `person`'s method/attribute, causing Hibernate to perform lazy fetching.  (There is another possibility that may be a bug of Hibernate, but I'd say the chance is low)

Comment: It looks like the JavaDoc for #getReference says it may throw an EntityNotFoundException if the entity does not exist in the database. I'm not sure how it could do that without a lookup. Have you looked at the Hibernate implementation for #getReference? It fires a LoadEvent. So it may just not be possible to do what I want.

Comment: afaik, the loading only happen when you are trying to access the reference (for which triggers a lazy loading).  If you are not accessing the reference, there is no loading.  ref: in javadoc:  the EntityNotFoundException is thrown ***when the instance state is first accessed*** .  Maybe Hibernate has changed its implementation but that's the behavior when I was using Hibernate 3.x, for which `getReference()` is using Hibernate's `Session#load()`, which is doing similar thing as what described in `getReference()` javadoc

Comment: Just one more thing to add, I haven't dig into Hibernate's code, but if LoadEvent is going to be cause Session#load() to be called, thne it is the desired behavior that you want: Hibernate's Session#load() either return the entity from 1st level cache (if it exists), or give you a proxy without DB access.

Comment: I figured it out. I do batch inserts. To make them efficient I have Hibernate order them. Hibernate's ordering algorithm invokes #hashCode and #equals on each object to be persisted. In my Address implementation of these I call #getId on the Person entity. I suppose because the proxy reference is based on #getId that I did not expect Hibernate to do a lookup from using JUST that method of the reference. Live and learn. Thanks for your help. I wouldn't call this a bug, but it certainly seems unnecessary.

Comment: Heh, actually it doesn't matter whether I use it in my hash or not. For ordered inserts hibernate will reflectively get all fields and hash them. :) So that is when the reference gets loaded.

Comment: I also hate Hibernate doing lazy fetching when accessing the ID of proxy :P  But at least, it prove that getReference()/Session#load() is not going to access DB if you are not accessing the proxy :)